# NoReverseMatch Exception in Django template URL path

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

I can access the desired URL but when it is added in another template as a hyperlink, the template fails to render.

So, when I try to access `http://127.0.0.1:8000/jobs/97072947-looking-for-woodcutter/add-milestones/`, it works.

But when I want to insert the above URL in **project_milestones**'s template:
`{% url 'projects:create_milestone' %}`

This error occurs when I open `http://127.0.0.1:8000/jobs/97072947-looking-for-woodcutter/milestones/`:

```
Request Method:  GET
Request URL:     http://127.0.0.1:8000/jobs/97072947-looking-for-woodcutter/milestones/
Django Version:  1.11.3
Exception Type:  NoReverseMatch
Exception Value: Reverse for 'create_milestone' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['jobs/(?P<project>[-\\w]+)/(add-milestones)/$']
Python Version:  3.6.1
```

views.py:

```
def project_milestones(request, project):
    project = get_object_or_404(Project, slug=project)
    ...code..
    return render(request, 'projects/employer_milestones_project.html' {'project': project,})


def create_milestone(request, project):
    project = get_object_or_404(Project, slug=project)
    ..code...
    return render(request, 'projects/employer_create_milestone.html',
                  {'project': project})
```

urls.py:

```
url(r'^'r'(?P<project>[-\w]+)/(add-milestones)/$',
    create_milestone, name='create_milestone'),

url(r'^'r'(?P<project>[-\w]+)/(milestones)/$',
    project_milestones, name='project_milestones'),
```

What am I missing here?  I have also tried `{% url 'projects:create_milestone' project=project.slug %}` but nothing seems to work. Also if I remove that built-in url tag, the page loads successfully.

I am sure the answer is somewhere here in [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/) or [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#url) but I am not able to understand. Sorry if question is not well structured. Thanks!

Comment: Probably becoz you have used single quotes multiple times in the url expression. Try to use single quotes within double quotes for best results.

Comment: I am sorry, can you explain?

Comment: instead of this
url(r'^'r'(?P<project>[-\w]+)/(add-milestones)/$', create_milestone, name='create_milestone')
use the following
url(r"^(?P<project>[-\w]+)/(add-milestones)/$",create_milestone, name='create_milestone')

Comment: It still doesn't work. Thank you though.

Comment: What happens if you simply use {%  url  'create_milestone'  %}

Comment: This error occurs: `Reverse for 'create_milestone' not found. 'create_milestone' is not a valid view function or pattern name.` namespaces are required no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues with your url patterns. Remove the `r'` inside the string, and remove the parentheses around add-milestone and milestones.

```
url(r'^(?P<project>[-\w]+)/add-milestones/$',
create_milestone, name='create_milestone'),
url(r'^(?P<project>[-\w]+)/milestones/$',
project_milestones, name='project_milestones'),
```